# JSP: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, google-chrome

I get an error on my *index.jsp*.

[image]

On page refresh I get a similar error but now includes a resource from a JS file.

[image]
[image]

I'd like to ask what what this error notation means.

```
GET http://localhost:8086/ProjectContext/container%20maincontainer 404 (Not Found)
```

***container maincontainer*** are CSS classes applied to my div.

```
<div class="container maincontainer">
```

The CSS file where these classes are defined is referenced through a relative URL.

```
<link href="assets/css/stylev2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but I also tried using absolute path and get the same error.

```
<link href="/ProjectContext/assets/css/stylev2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://localhost:8086/ProjectContext/assets/css/stylev2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Note: Crossed out are the context. *e.g ProjectContext***

Comment: Either your path is not correct or you don't have asset in the correct path. Try viewing the Elements tab to see if the JS and CSS loaded. Check your build path. Make sure your resources are included.

Comment: @Mukus I am pretty sure that the path is correct and that the folders and files exist. I tried viewing the elements tab and the CSS and JS are rendered. Also this is deployed on another server on my local machine and I checked if the resources are included, when the WAR file is extracted my resources are there.

Comment: If they're rendered when you view the elements tab why would the network tab say 404? I don't believe it is. Regardless try using "." in front of the "/" in the path and also check your build path to see if you've not included the location of these resources. If you're using an IDE check right clicking on the project should help, if not look at the .classpath file.

Comment: If all is good, check the version of jquery and jquery-ui and the order they appear in the jsp.